# RandomVariate form a Specific Distribution with Restrictions

Tags: random, distributions

There are a lot of questions about generating random numbers form both uni-variate and bi-variate distributions. Mathematica has a lot of built in distributions for that purpose. However, I could not do what I wanted to do. I am looking for help.

I want to generate random numbers using built in Mathematica distribution but would like to put some restriction. For example, the following code gives me 2000 random numbers form exponential distribution.

```
example1=RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[0.0067], 2000];
```

However, I am trying to get 2000 random variables greater than say 20 from exponential distribution. Similarly, the following code gives me 2000 random numbers a form Farlie-Gumbel-Morgenstern copula.

```
   example2=RandomVariate[
     CopulaDistribution[{"FGM", .34}, {NormalDistribution[0, 1], 
       ExponentialDistribution[0.0067]}], 2000];
```

However, I want to get 2000 random numbers form Normal distribution between -.02 and .02 or I want random numbers form exponential distribution between 40 and 1000.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `TruncatedDistribution` may be what you are after.

Comment: @ Andy, you are right. But I am also expecting some innovative answers, which I always get form this community.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
d1 = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[.1], 2000];
d2 = RandomVariate[TruncatedDistribution[{20, 40}, ExponentialDistribution[.1]], 2000];

GraphicsColumn[{Histogram[d1, {1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 72}, {0, 250}}],
                Histogram[d2, {1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 72}, {0, 250}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @ belisarius thank you for taking time to answer my question. This proves that I am a new user of Mathematica. However, I am expecting some more answers so I can play with. Thanks again.

Comment: @rka Feeling comfortable with mathematica takes some time. Be patient and keep trying